# Display:block is creating extra padding?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 span tags with the same class but one has an extra class which only adds a `display:block`. The problem is that the tag which has a `display:block` style creates an extra padding. If you put the two tags one next to the other you can notice the padding size difference. Is there a way to remove this extra padding for the tag with `display:block` ?

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/46q9J/)

And here's the two span tags zoom image, the one on the left is the one without display block. And the one on the right has a display: block.

[image]

PS: In this example the padding difference is negligible, but in my website, the difference is more than this.

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you need to use `<span>`? `<p>` doesn't have this issue

Comment: This is not a _padding_ issue, but an issue with height calculation based on the “box type” of an element, see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins This is not an easy matter, and how a possible “fix” could look like depends on the specifics of the situation and what exactly you want to achieve within them, but for that you have given not enough information.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for giving me this link, but still I need a solution. Basically, it will be useless to put more code or give more information because all I want is making both span of same size

Comment: @Amir http://jsfiddle.net/46q9J/3/ here both `<p>` are 13x20px while in your example `<span>` without `.block` is 13x19px

Comment: @Yesian_ yes it works. Can you write an answer so I can mark it solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<p>` instead.
Here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/46q9J/3/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, and this is due to box model. Use **span, p** or just manage to change the height of the block.

Another **not recommended answer** is not to use box model forcefully. 
See this

[box-sizing: content-box | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: coz it was me, I acidently created another account, I deleted that account now.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but can you suggest me a solution on my jsfiddle ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
//test code
.redButton:after {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   content: ".";
   font-size: 73px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 3px;
   top: -53px;
   z-index: 100;
 }
.redButton {
   background-color: #FF0000;
   border-radius: 10px;
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   font-size: 44px;
   height: 20px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   position: relative;
  width: 20px;
}
```